# Gutenberg how to save to post meta?

Tags: block-editor

I can't figure out how to save the changed attribute value to post meta, could somebody help?

I've registered the attribute altogether with my block:

```
register_meta('post', 'showUntil', array(
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'auth_callback' => function () {
        return current_user_can('edit_posts');
    },
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
    'show_in_rest'      => true,
    'single'            => true,
    'type'              => 'string',
));
```

I have the following attributes:

```
atrributes: {
    showUntil: {
        type: 'string',
        source: 'meta',
        meta: 'showUntil'
    },
}
```

I can update the value with `setAttribute` etc., but how to actually save the post meta?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should update the attribute too update the attribute, I do not know this `setState` function you are using, but attributes are not component local state

Comment: @TomJNowell you're right made a typo I meant `setAttribute` - that works on react side of the app, but when I save the post, the post_meta (not the block meta) is not created and saved.

Comment: @KarolínaVyskočilová have you already checked the [tutorial in the block editor handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/metabox/meta-block-1-intro/)?

Comment: @SallyCJ Uh, thanks for pointing that out! That works. I've found this: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/block-api/block-attributes/#meta and then some crazy stuff with dispatch which wasn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to read and save custom post meta in the Gutenberg block editor.

```
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import { useSelect, useDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
import { PanelBody, PanelRow, TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';
import { InspectorControls } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

/**
 * My Custom Block
 */
const MyCustomBlock = () => {
    const META_KEY = 'showUntil'; // This is your custom meta name
    const { editPost } = useDispatch('core/editor');
    const meta = useSelect((select) =>
        select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')
    );
    const { [META_KEY]: customMeta } = meta;

    const onCustomMetaChange = (newValue) => {
        editPost({
            meta: { ...meta, [META_KEY]: newValue },
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelBody title={__('Settings', 'textdomain')}>
                    <PanelRow>
                        <TextControl
                            label={__('Custom Meta', 'textdomain')}
                            value={customMeta}
                            onChange={onCustomMetaChange}
                        />
                    </PanelRow>
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>
        </div>
    );
};
```

You could also check this [complete tutorial of mine on how to create and manage the custom post meta on the Gutenberg block editor.](https://jeffreycarandang.com/how-to-enable-read-and-update-post-meta-in-the-wordpress-block-editor-gutenberg/)